# How many prime numbers are there in between $1000!+1$ and $1000!+1000$, inclusive?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

I know $1000!$ is not a prime number as any number $1000$ or less is a divisor, but how would I know if $1000!+1$ is prime? Any hints?

Also, use the above question to prove that you can find $n$ consecutive composite numbers.

Comment: You have only commented on determining whether or not $1000!+1$ is prime. What about the others in the range, do you have any thoughts on them?

Comment: $n!+r$ is divisible by $r$ for $2\le r\le n$

Comment: the question explicitly says inclusive

Comment: Your question about $1000!+1$ may be difficult.

Comment: $n!+1$ is [this](http://oeis.org/A038507) sequence; I concur with @AndréNicolas that knowing if it's prime is not easy.

Comment: typing "Is 1000! + 1 prime" into WolframAlpha.com yields the result "1000! + 1 is not a prime number".  However, no reason is given, and there is a complaint "Standard Computation Time Exceeded", so I don't trust the answer 100%.  In a previous MSE question, Wolfram Alpha gave answers to a quadratic question with real coefficients that required careful interpretation to make any sense of (to be less charitable, Wolfram Alpha was wrong).  I would guess WolframAlpha used some probabilistic primality test.  I sent WolframAlpha some feedback complaining about their confusing answer.

Comment: 1001 is not a prime as well, or we could have used Wilson's theorem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only non-trivial case is $n=1000!+1$.

However, you can easily check with a computer that $2^{n-1} \not \equiv 1 \pmod n$, thus it's not a prime number (it's just an instance of [Fermat primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test)). If you want to try this yourself, use an efficient [modular exponentiation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method).

You may also have a look at [FactorDB](http://factordb.com/index.php?query=1000!%2B1), which will give you a partial factorization:
$$1000! + 1 = 6563 \cdot 1190737 \cdot 115205557790605547 \cdot C_{2541}$$
where $C_{2541}$ is a composite number with 2541 decimal digits.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $k$ divides $1000!+k$, for every natural $k\le 1000$.

Comment: $k\ge0$ and $\ne1$ right?

Comment: It's still true for $k=1$, however it doesn't exclude primality.

Comment: That's a good hint when $k\ge 2$. At $k=1$ it's a big number, not clear whether prime or not.

Answer (score 4):

All the integers from $1000!+2$ up to $1000!+1000$ are clearly not prime, and a simple check verifies that $6563$ is a factor of $1000!+1$, so there are no primes in the list.

Comment: Please explain how to do this simple check.

Comment: It was a check using software. I used this command in pari/gp: N=1000!+1;forprime (p=1003,1000000,if (N%p==0,print(p))).   Just to see if there were any small prime factors, and I was lucky.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot give a proof, but the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A002981) entry on factorial primes claims that  $1000!+1$ is not prime, as 1000 isn't listed. This is likely a [proof-by-computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_proof), though.

As for the rest of the numbers in that range, everyone else has already mentioned that $k\mid n!+k$ for $1\leq k\leq n$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wolfram alpha to check. Not really elegant but effective :-)

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Is+1000%21%2B1+prime%3F